# How to set git config to use specific key for domain?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

How do you make a rule in your `~/.gitconfig` to tell git to use a specific SSH key for a specific project?

I have separate personal and professional accounts on Gitlab, and I want to use my personal SSH key when committing to most of my Gitlab repos, but I want to specify a separate key when committing to my professional Gitlab repos. Aside from keeping things neat and tidy, this is also required from a technical standpoint as Gitlab doesn't let you share SSH keys between two accounts.

Searching for this situation, I found numerous solutions, such as appending this to my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/git/my_professional_project/"]
    [user]
        email = "myuser@domain.com"
    [core]
        sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myuser_at_domain.pub"
```

In theory, this tells git that, whenever making commits inside the directory `~/git/my_professional_project/` to push commits via SSH with the key `~/.ssh/id_rsa_myuser_at_domain.pub`.

And I found this did indeed allow git to commit to my professional account. However, despite the "IncludeIf" statement, I found the side-effect of this was that it also made git use my professional key for all git commits, resulting in the notorious error:

```
You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there a mistake in my includeIf rule syntax? Why does this configuration force git to use the wrong SSH key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `includeIf` syntax is indeed incorrect.  What you've written is an `includeIf` section with no configuration settings, then a `user` section with an `email` setting, and then a `core` section with an `sshCommand` setting, albeit with some odd indenting.

If you want to use an `includeIf` section, you need to place the additional options in a separate file, and include that:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/git/my_professional_project/"]
    path = ~/.config/git/professional
```

Comment: Nevermind. I was testing via an initial checkout, which of course failed because it was not inside the project directory. I manually specified the key via `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/work.pub" git clone git@gitlab.com:workaccount/repo.git` for the initial checkout, then your solution works once I'm in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

The `includeIf` directive / section uses only one field, named `path`:

```
[includeIf "expression"]
    path = /path/to/file
```

You cannot add `core` and `user` *sections* in this file.  You must put the `[core]` and `[user]` directives in *another configuration file*.  You then use the `includeIf` directive (your existing condition is fine) with `path` to *tell Git where to find the other file*.

Comment: Strange. I found this setup on [this blog post](https://medium.com/uncaught-exception/setting-up-multiple-github-accounts-the-nicer-way-5ab732078a7e), where he claims this should be allowed.

Comment: @Cerin: either he doesn't realize it, or he does, but in effect, the `includeif` he has inside the file is just a comment to the effect that the file is based on some other file's `includeif` directive.